# Spring Security Login with a twist: users must activate their account before login

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

I have implemented spring security to protect sections of our website. I am using a DB (MongoDB) to store username/password. I implemented org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService to lookup the account details from the DB.

I still need to add another feature: account activation. After registration, we send an activation email to a user and if he clicks on it, we mark the account as activated in the DB. Users that have not activated their account, should not be allowed to log in and should be redirected to a page for that.

Any ideas on how to implement? I need to somehow hook into the login process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Custom AuthenticationManager is not needed**. This feature is already available in Spring Security. Take a look to the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html), you can see the `enabled` property. When you create the user, if you set that property to false and user try to login, Spring will display automatically a message informing the user that account is not active.

**UPDATED**

In order to display Spring error messages, you should use this in the login page:

```
<c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
```

Comment: thanks! great answer! how would I know in the JSP that the user was not authenticated due to account not enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom authentication manager where you can check if the user is activated or not

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter"     class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager"
        p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

and custom authenticationManager

```
<bean id="customAuthenticationManager"
        class="com.mycompany.security.CustomAuthenticationManager" />
```

**CustomAuthenticationManager.java**

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager{
        @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        User user = null;
        if (auth.getName() == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User does not exists!");
        }
        user = userService.getUserByUsername(auth.getName());
        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User does not exists!");
        }
        if (passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.getPassword(), (String) auth.getCredentials(), null)) {
            //check if user is activated if not throw appropriate excetion
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User does not exists!");
        }

    }
```

and it will redirect user back to login page (if configured properly)

now in login.jsp, get the failure reason by

```
${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
```

and show the appropriate message to user
}

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how would I redirect to another page then?

Comment: Custom AuthenticationManager is not needed. "enable" property from UserDetails should be used.